# Unity Neatplug does not support iOS 64bit

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store, ads

I want to upgrade my app which was already published on App Store.
But I got warning message from App Store when I uploaded it.
So I converted my app to 64Bit one.
I developed it with unity, so I set Scripting Backend to IL2CPP and converted project to XCode one.
Then I got these errors on XCode.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  **"__em_AdmobAd_SetBannerAdSize", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_SetBannerAdSize_m8615(Object_t*, int, int, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z44AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_SetBannerAdSize_m8615P8Object_tiiP10MethodInfo, _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_SetBannerAdSize_m8615_MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_GetAdSizeInPixels", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_GetAdSizeInPixels_m8614(Object_t*, int, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS_GetAdSizeInPixels_m2286(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, int, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z46AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_GetAdSizeInPixels_m8614P8Object_tiP10MethodInfo, _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_GetAdSizeInPixels_m8614_MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_EnableAd", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_EnableAd_m8612(Object_t*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS_EnableAd_m2284(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z37AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_EnableAd_m8612P8Object_tP10MethodInfo, _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_EnableAd_m8612_MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_RepositionBannerAd", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_RepositionBannerAd_m8607(Object_t*, int, int, int, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS_RepositionBannerAd_m2279(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, int, int, int, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_RepositionBannerAd_m8607_MethodInfo, __Z47AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_RepositionBannerAd_m8607P8Object_tiiiP10MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAd", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAd_m8601(Object_t*, int, int, int, int, bool, String_t*, int, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdAbs_m8602_MethodInfo, _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdCustomSize_m8603_MethodInfo , __Z51AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdCustomSize_m8603P8Object_tiiiiibP8String_tiP10MethodInfo , __Z41AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAd_m8601P8Object_tiiiibP8String_tiP10MethodInfo , _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAd_m8601_MethodInfo , __Z44AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdAbs_m8602P8Object_tiiibP8String_tiP10MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_Init", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_Init_m8599(Object_t*, String_t*, String_t*, bool, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z33AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_Init_m8599P8Object_tP8String_tS2_bP10MethodInfo, _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_Init_m8599_MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_ShowInterstitialAd", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS_ShowInterstitialAd_m2282(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_ShowInterstitialAd_m8610(Object_t*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z47AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_ShowInterstitialAd_m8610P8Object_tP10MethodInfo, _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_ShowInterstitialAd_m8610_MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_ShowBannerAd", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS_ShowBannerAd_m2277(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_ShowBannerAd_m8605(Object_t*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_ShowBannerAd_m8605_MethodInfo, __Z41AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_ShowBannerAd_m8605P8Object_tP10MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_DestroyBannerAd", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS_DestroyBannerAd_m2280(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_DestroyBannerAd_m8608(Object_t*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS_DisableAd_m2283(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_DestroyBannerAd_m8608_MethodInfo, __Z44AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_DestroyBannerAd_m8608P8Object_tP10MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_RefreshBannerAd", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS_RefreshBannerAd_m2276(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_RefreshBannerAd_m8604(Object_t*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z44AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_RefreshBannerAd_m8604P8Object_tP10MethodInfo, _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_RefreshBannerAd_m8604_MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdAbs", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdAbs_m8602(Object_t*, int, int, int, bool, String_t*, int, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdAbs_m8602_MethodInfo, __Z44AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdAbs_m8602P8Object_tiiibP8String_tiP10MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_HideBannerAd", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS_HideBannerAd_m2278(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_HideBannerAd_m8606(Object_t*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_HideBannerAd_m8606_MethodInfo, __Z41AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_HideBannerAd_m8606P8Object_tP10MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdCustomSize", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdCustomSize_m8603(Object_t*, int, int, int, int, int, bool, String_t*, int, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdCustomSize_m8603_MethodInfo, __Z51AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadBannerAdCustomSize_m8603P8Object_tiiiiibP8String_tiP10MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_SetTestMode", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_SetTestMode_m8600(Object_t*, bool, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS_SetTestMode_m2271(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, bool, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_SetTestMode_m8600_MethodInfo, __Z40AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_SetTestMode_m8600P8Object_tbP10MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_DisableAd", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_DisableAd_m8611(Object_t*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS_DisableAd_m2283(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_DisableAd_m8611_MethodInfo, __Z38AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_DisableAd_m8611P8Object_tP10MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_LoadInterstitialAd", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadInterstitialAd_m8609(Object_t*, bool, String_t*, int, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadInterstitialAd_m8609_MethodInfo, __Z47AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_LoadInterstitialAd_m8609P8Object_tbP8String_tiP10MethodInfo )
  **"__em_AdmobAd_IsAdEnabled", referenced from:**
      AdmobAdIOS_IsAdEnabled_m2285(AdmobAdIOS_t393*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
      AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_IsAdEnabled_m8613(Object_t*, MethodInfo*) in Bulk_AdmobAdLib_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_IsAdEnabled_m8613_MethodInfo, __Z40AdmobAdIOS__em_AdmobAd_IsAdEnabled_m8613P8Object_tP10MethodInfo )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

I used Neatplug for Ads and I think it was the cause of this issue.
I downloaded this plugin several months ago, so I do not know that this plugin supports 64bit iOS now. I don`t know well about XCode. If it was not the main cause of this issue, please help me how can I solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you might be missing the 64-bit libraries for the Neatplug asset (although I'm not specifically familiar with Neatplug). You can confirm this by change the "Architecture" option in the iOS player settings in Unity to be "ARMv7". That will only build the ARMv7 slice in Xcode, which should be the same thing your were building with the Mono scripting backend. You can't submit that, but it is a good troubleshooting step.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I built it without errors to set ARM7 already. So at that time I could test it. But when I uploaded it, I couldn`t it. Do you mean that I have to find the library which is suitable for iOS 64Bit?

Comment: Yes, Since it builds with ARMv7, then the native library here probably is not built for ARM64 as well. You'll need to obtain the ARM64 version.

Comment: I found it. It works well without any issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up with an answer to this question then. The problem was missing ARM64 binaries for a native library. Note that any native libraries will need to be built for both ARMv7 and ARM64 now.